# Explain this class,subclass,exception code, please

Tags: python

```
class AndTrigger(Trigger):
    def __init__(self,object1,object2):
        self.object1 = object1
        self.object2 = object2
    def evaluate(self,object):
        return self.object1.evaluate(self) and self.object2.evaluate(self)
```

I implemented this AND trigger and it works as it is supposed to, but I was only able to make it work by trial and error--I have no idea what 'self' is doing in this class.

Here's what I think is going on: the `__init__` is the constructor for the class, so any instance of the class uses this when created. The class has two attributes (object1, object2), the `__init__` when the class is created tells the new instance that these new attributes will be called 'object1' and 'object2' so they are assigned to self.object1 etc.

Now, this evaluate function is supposed to prevent a raise notimplemented in Trigger, but that's not what I don't get. In this evaluate function, it looks like it has two arguments--the instance of AndTrigger and another object. But where is this other object in the definition of `evaluate()`? It's just a puzzle to me how this works, but it does!

Comment: `object` is not used at all in `evaluate`. It is being ignored.

Comment: If you don't know what `self` is, you need to read up on basic object usage in Python. Also, if this is all there is to your object and you don't plan to add more, this is a classic example of making an object where you don't need one - this is a function as it stands.

Comment: Also, your wording is pretty unclear - you seem to use *aspect* as a synonym to *attribute*, for example.

Comment: It's an assignment. We need to make an object regardless of your tastes. Your comments are not helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're calling a bound member function, the first argument (`self`) is supplied automatically. It refers to the object on which the function is invoked.

Let's for the sake of illustration assume that both `self.object1` and `self.object2` are of type `TriggerX`. The following:

```
def evaluate(self, obj):
    return self.object1.evaluate(self) and self.object2.evaluate(self)
```

is then equivalent to:

```
def evaluate(self, obj):
    return TriggerX.evaluate(self.object1, self) and TriggerX.evaluate(self.object2, self)
```

I hope this clears things up.

P.S. I suspect from the context that the following:

```
def evaluate(self, obj):
    return self.object1.evaluate(self) and self.object2.evaluate(self)
```

should be

```
def evaluate(self, obj):
    return self.object1.evaluate(obj) and self.object2.evaluate(obj)
```

P.P.S. Please don't use `object` as a variable name, since this shadows a built-in class.

Comment: Well, `object` is used when declaring a class, for example: `class TriggerX(object):` to create a "new-style" class, so I thought I was referring to the same base class `object` in the method.